# Calcular la edad mediante fecha actual en C

Tags: c, date, estructuras-de-datos

He realizado un código simple para guardas datos de personas en una estructura y se me a ocurrido, sacar la edad de la persona mediante el método fechaActual() restarlo del algún modo con la fecha de nacimiento introducida..

Codigo:

```
struct fecha{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anio;
}fecha;

struct datosPersonales{
    char DNI[10];
    char nombre[30];
    char apellidos[50];
    struct fecha fechaNacimiento;
    int seguridadSocial;
}persona[2];

//Prototipos de funciones
void introducirDatos();
void visualizarDatos();
void fechaActual();

int main()
{
    printf("DATOS DE PERSONAS EN ESTRUCTURAS\n\n");
    introducirDatos();
    system("CLS");
    printf("DATOS INTRODUCIDOS\n\n");
    visualizarDatos();
    fechaActual();

    return 0;
}

void introducirDatos()
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Datos de la %d persona\n",i+1);
        printf("DNI: ");
        gets(persona[i].DNI);
        printf("Nombre: ");
        gets(persona[i].nombre);
        printf("Apellidos: ");
        gets(persona[i].apellidos);
        printf("Fecha de nacimiento\n");
        printf("Dia: ");
        scanf("%d",&persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia);
        printf("Mes: ");
        scanf("%d",&persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes);
        printf("A%co: ",164);
        scanf("%d",&persona[i].fechaNacimiento.anio);
        printf("Numero de la Seguridad Social: ");
        scanf("%d",&persona[i].seguridadSocial);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void visualizarDatos()
{
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
        printf("Datos de la %d persona\n",i+1);
        printf("DNI = %s\n",persona[i].DNI);
        printf("Nombre = %s\n",persona[i].nombre);
        printf("Apellidos = %s\n",persona[i].apellidos);
        printf("Fecha de nacimiento = %d/%d/%d\n",persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia,persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes,
                                            persona[i].fechaNacimiento.anio);                               
        printf("Numero de la Seguridad Social = %d\n\n",persona[i].seguridadSocial);                                        
    }
}

void fechaActual()
{
    time_t tiempo = time(0);
    struct tm *tlocal = localtime(&tiempo);
    char output[128];
    strftime(output,128,"%d/%m/%y",tlocal);
    printf("%s\n",output);
 }
```

Comment: Hola Mario. Y que problema tienes con tu intento de `fechaActual`?  Por favor, explica mejor que problemas tiene: errore, resultado no esperado.. Mira [ask] para aprender a hacer mejores preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: Errores no tengo, solo que no se como implementarlo para sacar la edad de la persona

Comment: Mario, has de intentarlo tu mismo y si tienes problemas, preguntar aqui. Si no sabes por donde empezar a orientarte siempre puedes preguntar en el [chat]. Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes echarle un vistazo a esta programación para ver como lo hacen en el ejemplo que muestran:
[Ejemplo](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/age-calculator.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La fecha de nacimiento veo que ya puedes cogerla en

```
persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia
persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes
persona[i].fechaNacimiento.anio
```

Y con la funcion *fechaActual()* ya tienes la fecha actual. Simplemente compara las dos fechas para calcular la diferencia del siguiente modo: [Difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932909/difference-between-two-dates-in-c)

En el ejemplo también recoge la fecha en 3 partes (dia, mes y año), por lo que te facilita la adaptación a tu código.

```
  //c_date representa "Current date" o dia actual
  //diferencia representa la diferencia entre las dos fechas 

  //Si el dia de la fecha actual es mayor o igual al de nacimiento > calculamos diferencia
  if(c_date.dd>=persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia)
    diferencia.dd = c_date.dd-persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia;
  //Por lo contrario añadimos 30 dias pero restamos 1 mes y calculamos diferencia
  else
  {
      c_date.dd+=30;
      c_date.mm-=1;
      diferencia.dd = c_date.dd-persona[i].fechaNacimiento.dia;
   }
   //Lo mismo con los meses
   if(c_date.mm>=persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes)
     diferencia.mm = c_date.mm-persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes;
   else
   {
      c_date.mm+=12;
      c_date.yy-=1;
      diferencia.mm = c_date.dd-persona[i].fechaNacimiento.mes;
   }
   //Igual con los años
   diferencia.yy = c_date.yy-persona[i].fechaNacimiento.anio;
```

Comment: Perfecto amigo, me servirá, gracias!!